# Why motional emf is induced when a one dimensional object moves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity, rotation

Suppose we have a conducting rod hinged about a certain point in uniform magnetic field . When we start to rotate the rod with constant angular velocity ω, there will an induced emf of

e = BωL<sup>2</sup>/2

Where L = length of the rod.

But there is no change in flux as there is no loop so why is an emf induced?

Comment: It's about the number of field lines being cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop terminology is not very correct for this since there is no loop technically. Your EMF is $$\epsilon = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$ so it is dependent on change in flux with time. Flux is basically by definition about field lines passing through anything. Now when your rod is rotating at different instance different field lines are crossing it, it's not the same field lines throughout. This is what creates the emf.

Comment: So how do we define Φ for the formula in order to calculate emf  according to faraday's law?

Comment: @GarvChaudha $\Phi$ would still be the $\vec{B} \cdot \vec{A}$ so $\Phi = B \times \frac{l^2 \theta}{2}$ now if we take the differential with time the $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \omega$ and you would get the emf equation given in your question

Comment: @GarvChaudha [Source of derivation](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_%28OpenStax%29/Book%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_%28OpenStax%29/13%3A_Electromagnetic_Induction/13.04%3A_Motional_Emf)